# Python numpy loadtxt: reading an empty file into an array with a particular number of columns

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, file-io

Is there a way to let `numpy.loadtxt(fname, ..)` create an array of shape `(0, ncol)`, where `ncol` is an intenger specified by me, when `fname` is an empty file?

For example, if I run the following script,

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy as np

aa = np.loadtxt('fanmab.dat', ndmin=2)
print('aa.shape=',  aa.shape)

ae = np.loadtxt('fempty.dat', ndmin=2)
#ae = np.loadtxt('fempty.dat', ndmin=2, usecols=(0,1,2,3))
print('ae.shape=',  ae.shape)
```

with the files, `fanmab.dat`

```
# This is fanmab.dat
0.1234   0.56    0.78    0.90
1.1234   1.56    1.78    1.90
2.1234   2.56    2.78    2.90
```

and `fempty.dat`

```
# This is an empty file
```

I see the following stdout from python

```
$ ./main.py 
aa.shape= (3, 4)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py:816: UserWarning: loadtxt: Empty input file: "fempty.dat"
  warnings.warn('loadtxt: Empty input file: "%s"' % fname)
ae.shape= (0, 1)
```

The length of the second dimension seems to be set automatically as `1` when there is no line to read-in but `ndmin=2`. Setting `usecols` did not seem to help.

Do I need to do something like the following?

```
if ae.shape[0]==0:
    ae.reshape((0,ncol))
```

Comment: `if ae.size == 0: ae = ae.reshape((0, ncol))`

Comment: Or just a conditional `ae = zeros((0, ncol))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
ae = np.loadtxt(..., ndmin=2).reshape(-1, 4)
```

will work for both cases. The `-1` tells NumPy to guess the number of rows based on the size of the flattened input array.